# Vagrant access is denied

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Windows 8.1. I get "access is denied" when i execute

```
vagrant
```

using windows command prompt, but it works well using Git Bash (msysgit)

[image: This app can't run on your PC]

[image: vagrant, windows command prompt and msysgit]

I reinstall vagrant, but still access denied.
Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe run the windows command prompt as administrator ? BTW this question may be off-topic.

Comment: doesn't work. where to go? superuser?

Comment: Suggest you try `vagrant version --debug`. This may give you enough feedback to determine the root cause of your issue.

Comment: Did you run the Vagrant installer as Administrator?

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue. 
How I solved the problem is by assigning/setting `VAGRANT_HOME`
It was not present by default because as i had installed vagrant in other directory, in my case it was D.

Just run this command on powershell/cmd and make sure you have administrator rights

```
setx VAGRANT_HOME "D:\your\path\vagrant.exe"
```

After executing the command sign out and sign in

[Link](https://harvsworld.com/2014/change-vagrant_home-directory-windows/) for reference

There is a chance that things might not properly and you may get ERRNO:EXISTS kind of error. To solve this error make sure the user on which you have installed virtualbox is the one who using vagrant commands are SAME.
[Link](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/common-issues.html) for reference

Answer (score 0):

use  `vagrant --debug` to print stacktrace log.
You dont have permission to run powershell because vagrant use powershell to execute commands.
you can also check powershell status with `vagrant powershell`
Make sure you have the rights permission on powershell